# Android: UI freezes although use of Handler and postdelay

Tags: android, user-interface, handler

My app works with a few pictures. I want to take a new one every few seconds and add it to the pictures I work with. So I wrote this code, using an own Thread for the waiting time, so the ui won't freeze.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int time = 500;
for (int cnt = 10000; cnt > 0; cnt -= time) {
     // Execute the code in run after time [ms] passed
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             mainTask();
         }
     }, time);
}
```

Why does my ui freeze until the for loop ends? Usually the shown pictures should be updated in the `mainTask()`

Thanks for your help!

**[EDIT]**

It is working now, I created a class that implements Runnable and let it call itself:

```
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            class DelayedTask implements Runnable {
                int cnt, time;
                Handler handler;
                DelayedTask(int c, int t, Handler h) {cnt=c; time=t; handler=h;}
                public void run() {
                    mainTask();
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        cnt -= time;
                        handler.postDelayed(new DelayedTask(cnt, time, handler), time);
                    }
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(new DelayedTask(cnt,time,handler), time);
```

Comment: Are you sure, you not running this code on UI thread? Calling to new Handler() on thread without looper attached will cause an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're scheduling 10000/500 `Runnable`s in a *very* short time, all firing after 500ms, at the same time. This is probably not what you want.

Instead, you want to schedule the next `Runnable` when the current `Runnable` fires:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    mainTask();

    if(someCondition) {
      handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

Now, `mainTask` will fire every ~500ms.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand the concept now better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but I think the handler goes like this:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainTask();
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    }, interval);
```